# Icon is not embedding into search bar and positioned outside of div

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, searchbar

I have a search bar and I am trying to embed a font awesome icon, however it does not seem to be getting wrapped within the container div

Here is an image which shows where the icon currently is and I want the search icon to go

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you

[image]

CSS:

```
 @import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");


    .searchbar{
            position:relative;

        }

        .searchbar input { text-indent: 32px;}
        .searchbar .fa-search { 
          position: absolute;
          top: 10px;
          left: 10px;
            color: #4f5b66;

        }

.search_field {
    min-width: 270px;
    width: 65%;
    height:40px;
    font-size: 2em;
    behavior: url(js/PIE.htc);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: -4px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float:right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="searchbar">
   <form method="GET" action="search.php" style= "padding: 1px; font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;">
                <span class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></span>
                <input type="text" name="search" class="search_field" value="<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>" id="search" maxlength="20" />
                <input type="hidden" name="start" value="0" />
                <input type="hidden" name="limit" value="10" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your input on a div, position that DIV exactly where you want the text input to be, and then set the DIV to position relative. Also place your icon inside this DIV.

On another note, if you ICON is supposed to be clickable for submit purposes, dont use a span, either use a 'button' tag or an actual input-type:submit

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have tried to wrap input with the div `<div class="searchbar">`please could you elaborate on how I would go about wrapping it correctly?

Comment: thanks again this is perfect! very much appreciated!